# Not able to finish setting up LUKS

Tags: arch-linux, lvm, luks

I am trying to encrypt a new VM with LVM on LUKS.

I formatted and partitioned the HD (1 partition).
I ran:

```
# cryptsetup -c aes-xts-plain64 -s 512 luksFormat /dev/sda1 /mnt/dok/31.jpg
```

typing "yes".

Everything looks ok, however when runing:

```
# crypysetup open --type luks /dev/sda1 lvm --key-file=/mnt/dok/31.jpg
```

There is an error message:  "sda1 is not a valid LUKS device."

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it supposed to be /mnt/dok or /mnt/don?

Comment: dok - sorry, fixed.

Comment: When asked `Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes):`, do you type uppercase `YES` as instructed or just plain `yes`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to type uppercase `YES` for `luksFormat` to succeed. You can check for success by looking if the return code is non-zero:

```
root@host1:~# cryptsetup -c aes-xts-plain64 -s 512 luksFormat /dev/sda1 /somefile
...
Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): yes
root@host1:~# echo $?
1
```

1 means it stopped and didn't do anything (or failed).

```
root@host1:~# cryptsetup -c aes-xts-plain64 -s 512 luksFormat /dev/sda1 /somefile
...
Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
root@host1:~# echo $?
0
```

0 means the partition is now in luks format.

Comment: i have finished the process but after the reboot i get black screen :( starting again from scratch :((

Comment: Hi guys. i have re-installed the system now trying to configure grub to ext USB: # grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck --debug --boot-directory=/mnt//boot /dev/sdc    seemed ok but when trying to run the:  # grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg    i get the following: failed to get canonical path of 'airootfs'

Comment: @Talb21, this is another problem, so you'd probably need to raise a new question. If you do so, try entering as many details as you can in the description. If you miss an important detail it might mean you won't get much help. If you are following some guidelines or howto on the internet, point it out and also mention any variations you might have taken in the steps. Feel free to accept my answer if it allowed you to proceed.